# What is meant by the term “borrowing energy from the vacuum” in quantum physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy-conservation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, vacuum, virtual-particles

What is meant by “borrowing energy from the vacuum” seems like a totally illogical statement and a violation of conservation of energy

Comment: You are right that energy is conserved in every process and subprocess, even line of a Feynman diagram. This is language used *metaphorically* for special virtual states which do not have a  predictable mass (they are off the mass shell) and are accounted for in this metaphorical language, which you will learn in a specialized course.

Answer (score 0):

You can violate energy conservation on the subatomic level, *but only for very short times*- after which the debt must be paid back. The more energy you borrow, the sooner you must give it back. Note that on macroscopic time and distance scales, you can't get away with this.

Comment: where does this energy that is borrowed come from? Because the word “vacuum” kind of suggests it comes from empty space. I.e. empty with no energy.

Comment: Empty space is not empty, it is full of quantum fields that vary rapidly on extremely small distance and time scales.

Comment: What are “quantum fields” made from if they occupy empty space they have to occupy a measurable volume.

Comment: dozens of books have been written on quantum field theory. search on that for more info.